# c++ regex get folder from a file path

Tags: c++, regex

I have a file name like this

`/mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/2011022669-5126858992107.vtt`

how to replace the file name with `*` using regex so I get

`/mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/*`?

I know the simple for loop split or `boost::filesystem` approach, I'm looking for a `regex_replace` approach.

Comment: I suggest *trying* rather than just *looking*. Have you come up with any code so far?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need regexp for this:

```
string str = "/mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/2011022669-5126858992107.vtt";
auto lastSlash = str.find_last_of('/');
str.replace(str.begin() + lastSlash + 1, str.end(), "*");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern

```
(([\w+\-])+)(?=(\.\w{3}))
```

tested in notepad++.

(?=()) its lookahaed. So it will match ([\w+-])+ only if extension (.\w{2,3)) in format .xxx or .xx is after this group.
In c++ you have to just replace group to * something like
replace (string, $1 , '*') -- i don't know c++ replace funciton, just assuming.

$1,$2,$3... its group number, in this case - $1 its (([\w+-])+).

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution with regexp_replace [[live]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3eaa1611ef1660ff):

```
   std::string path = "/mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/2011022669-5126858992107.vtt";
   std::regex re(R"(\/[^\/]*?\..+$)");

   std::cout << path << '\n';
   std::cout << std::regex_replace(path, re, "/*") << '\n';
```

outputs:

> /mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/2011022669-5126858992107.vtt
>   /mnt/opt/storage/ssd/subtitles/8/vtt/*

but,... regexp seems to be a bit too heavy weight for such simple replacement